# Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`SocialLogin`)

Tags: reactjs, components

const [signInWithGoogle, user, loading, error] = useSignInWithGoogle(auth);
const [signInWithGithub, user1, loading1, error1] = useSignInWithGithub(auth);
const [signInWithFacebook, user2, loading2, error2] = useSignInWithFacebook(auth);
const navigate = useNavigate();

```
let errorElement;

if (error || error1 || error2) {
    errorElement =  <p className='text-center text-danger'>Error: {error?.message} {error1?.message} {error2?.message}</p>
}

if (loading || loading1 || loading2) {
    return <Loading></Loading>
}

if (user || user1 || user2) {
    navigate('/home');
}
```

Comment: That probably comes from an anti pattern somewhere and can be complex to identify.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, I will clarify this more specifically